# Installation of Sympy Gamma in windows

Tags: sympy

I have been trying to install Sympy Gamma in Windows for the last 2 days, but some issue is preventing it from functioning. I have done the followings

> 1. Installed python 2.7
> 2. Downloaded and unpacked most recent Google App Engine SDK for Python from http://code.google.com/appengine/downloads.html
> 3. Cloned sympy_gamma repository (git clone git://github.com/sympy/sympy_gamma.git , cd sympy_gamma , git
>      submodule init, git submodule update)
> 4. Installed PIP, PIL, docutils  and  Django
> 5. Run development web server ($ ../google_appengine/dev_appserver.py .)

I got the console as

```
INFO     2014-04-27 22:55:46,936 sdk_update_checker.py:242] Checking for updates to the SDK.
INFO     2014-04-27 22:55:49,645 sdk_update_checker.py:286] This SDK release is newer than the advertise
INFO     2014-04-27 22:55:49,809 api_server.py:171] Starting API server at: http://localhost:51944
INFO     2014-04-27 22:55:49,813 dispatcher.py:182] Starting module "default" running at: http://localho
INFO     2014-04-27 22:55:49,816 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
```

But when I am trying `http://localhost:8080/` , a blank screen is coming up and the console log comes up as given below

```
ERROR    2014-04-27 17:33:09,907 base.py:209] Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\django-1.3\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 101, in get_response
    request.path_info)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\django-1.3\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 252, in resolve
    sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\django-1.3\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 158, in resolve
    return ResolverMatch(self.callback, args, kwargs, self.name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\django-1.3\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 164, in _get_callback
    self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\django-1.3\django\utils\functional.py", line 124, in wrapper
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\django-1.3\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 91, in get_callable
    lookup_view = getattr(import_module(mod_name), func_name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\django-1.3\django\utils\importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\sympy_gamma\app\views.py", line 16, in <module>
    import settings
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\sympy_gamma\app\settings.py", line 1
    ../settings.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
ERROR    2014-04-27 17:33:09,926 wsgi.py:278]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 266, in Handle
    result = handler(dict(self._environ), self._StartResponse)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\django-1.3\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 272, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\django-1.3\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 169, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\django-1.3\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 217, in handle_uncaught_exceptio
    callback, param_dict = resolver.resolve500()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\django-1.3\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 303, in resolve500
    return self._resolve_special('500')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\django-1.3\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 295, in _resolve_special
    return get_callable(callback), {}
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\django-1.3\django\utils\functional.py", line 124, in wrapper
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\django-1.3\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 91, in get_callable
    lookup_view = getattr(import_module(mod_name), func_name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\django-1.3\django\utils\importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\sympy_gamma\app\views.py", line 16, in <module>
    import settings
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\sympy_gamma\app\settings.py", line 1
    ../settings.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
INFO     2014-04-27 23:03:09,969 module.py:627] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
INFO     2014-04-27 23:03:10,065 module.py:627] default: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2014-04-27 23:03:10,069 module.py:627] default: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

Could any of you please help me if you know why this error is coming up?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I got this error fixed.

I replaced google_appengine\sympy_gamma\app\settings.py 
with google_appengine\sympy_gamma\settings.py

Comment: Replaced it where? If somewhere in the Gamma source code is using `/`, it should be changed to use `os.path.join`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a link to the sympy_gamma/app/settings.py as sympy_gamma/settings.py, if it was not present in the first place then there was some problem while cloning/downloading. It is there in the sympy_gamma's repository.